# select2 programmatically without knowing results in advance

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-select2

I am trying to write a test for a Javascript select2 control and I would like to automatically select the first item.  Since it's using ajax I do not know what the first item is.  All the examples I have seen create `<option>` however they assume knowledge of the value.  How can I select the first item without knowledge?  (Note this example only runs the ajax command after 3 items are entered).

```
var $selector = $("#foo");
$selector.show().select2({
    allowClear: true,
    placeholder: "--------",
    minimumInputLength: 3,
    ajax: {
        url: "...",
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        data: function(term, page) {
            return {

                number__icontains: term
            };
        },
        results: function(data) {
            return {
                results: $.map(data.objects, function(option) {
                    return {
                        'id': option.id,
                        'text': option.desc
                    };
                })
            };
        },
        cache: false
    },
    initSelection: function(element, callback) {
        ...
    }
});
```

Comment: By "first item," you mean the first "real" item — not the placeholder, correct?

Comment: Do you want to select the first item automatically after the user write 3 letters?

Comment: Essentially I am trying to get my automated script to select an item in this list.  It could be any valid item on the list.  I mentioned the first item just as an example. Thanks for your help in advance.  Not a placeholder because I don't know what the website will return... although I know the first 3 digits for the text entry which will return a list.